# With Copied XPath it doesn't find the cookies in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to accept cookies by clicking a button.

```
<div class="message-component message-row" style="padding: 0px; margin: 10px; border-width: 0px; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-radius: 0px; border-style: solid; width: auto; height: auto; justify-content: center; align-items: center;"><button title="MORE OPTIONS" aria-label="MORE OPTIONS" class="message-component message-button no-children focusable sp_choice_type_12" style="padding: 15px; margin: 0px 10px; border-width: 1px; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-radius: 0px; border-style: solid; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; width: calc(50% - 50px); background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">MORE OPTIONS</button><button title="ACCEPT ALL" aria-label="ACCEPT ALL" class="message-component message-button no-children focusable sp_choice_type_11" style="padding: 15px; margin: 0px 10px; border-width: 1px; border-color: rgb(16, 23, 60); border-radius: 0px; border-style: solid; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; width: calc(50% - 50px); background: rgb(16, 23, 60);">ACCEPT ALL</button></div>
```

This is the button:

```
<button title="MORE OPTIONS" aria-label="MORE OPTIONS" class="message-component message-button no-children focusable sp_choice_type_12" style="padding: 15px; margin: 0px 10px; border-width: 1px; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-radius: 0px; border-style: solid; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; width: calc(50% - 50px); background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">MORE OPTIONS</button><button title="ACCEPT ALL" aria-label="ACCEPT ALL" class="message-component message-button no-children focusable sp_choice_type_11" style="padding: 15px; margin: 0px 10px; border-width: 1px; border-color: rgb(16, 23, 60); border-radius: 0px; border-style: solid; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; width: calc(50% - 50px); background: rgb(16, 23, 60);">ACCEPT ALL</button>
```

I've already tried this:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[2]/div[4]/button[2]')))
element.click()
```

I also tried with the implicit wait but it doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tough to solve your exact problem without context, since I don't know the site and the button specifically, but this should hopefully help click your button:

- Inspect the element.
- Go to copy options.
- Click "Copy selector".

  cookie_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "insert your copied selector here")

  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", cookie_button)

I don't know why but Stack Overflow really doesn't want to accept these 2 lines as code no matter what I do (I think there is a known bug regarding bullet points or lists and code samples not formatting properly), so sorry for that.

Comment: It's doesn't work, the output is the same selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException, so it doesn't find anything

Comment: Okay then please provide me with what you're trying to scrape so I can actually help you instead of guessing.

Comment: The site is this: "https://renderz.app/24/players". 
The button is
'<button title="ACCEPT ALL" aria-label="ACCEPT ALL" class="message-component message-button no-children focusable sp_choice_type_11" style="padding: 15px 12px; margin: 0px 10px; border-width: 1px; border-color: rgb(16, 23, 60); border-radius: 0px; border-style: solid; font-size: 15px; font-weight: 700; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; width: calc(47% - 44px); background: rgb(16, 23, 60);">ACCEPT ALL</button>'
You need to enter the site with incognito mode else it wont be visibile.